# Find Non-Matching Values Between Multiple Ranges

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, range

I am looking to see if there is a formula only (no VBA) way to find the values in a list of constants that are not in a range; and can be dynamically adjusted for different lengths of lists and with different column counts. Such as: Table 1 is a 3x2, Table 2 is 4x9, Table 3 is 6x8. The list of constants will always be the same length as the table they are for.

The list of constants {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J"}.

```
Column 1  Column 2  Column 3
A         J
C         B
G         E
I
*Blank Row*
*Blank Row*
*Blank Row*
*Blank Row*
*Blank Row*
*Blank Row*
```

I am looking for a formula that can list in Column 3 the values from the list of constants that are not in Columns 1-2. In this example, Column 3 would look like:

```
Column 3
D
F
H
*Blank Row*
*Blank Row*
*Blank Row*
*Blank Row*
*Blank Row*
*Blank Row*
*Blank Row*
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list of constants {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J"} put inside the formula,

and,

In "Column 3" `D2`, formula copied down :

```
=IFERROR(INDEX({"A";"B";"C";"D";"E";"F";"G";"H";"I";"J"},SMALL(IF(COUNTIF($A$2:$B$5,{"A";"B";"C";"D";"E";"F";"G";"H";"I";"J"}),4^8,ROW($1:$10)),ROWS($1:1))),"")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. This was exactly what I was looking for. I wasn't sure if it could be done, but you did it.

Answer (score 0):

This is reverse thinking, and what we generally do is return a value if it is within the specified condition range.

Anyway, in order to fulfill your needs, I suggest you add a secondary column, which is "test" in my test.

The column then uses the following formula:

```
=COUNTIF($B$2:$C$11,A2)
```

It confirms whether constant A has appeared in the conditional areas of Column A :Column B. If it appears, it returns 1

[image]

The next thing we need to do is use the following formula in column3:

```
=LOOKUP(0,D2,A2:A11)
```

[image]

It will return the value of "0" corresponding to the "range" column.